# Is the order of messages sent by SignalR constant on the client?

Tags: signalr

I have fairly simple question regarding SignalR, is it possible that SignalR messages would arrive in an out of sync order. i.e if you send messages A,B,C from server, is it possible that the client might get those messages in an order other than A,B,C?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything guaranteeing the equal performance of delivery back to the client assuming independent message calls. You would need to consider handling this on the client side. Of course if you are running the server async that would have an impact as well.